# Handling optional HTTP parameters in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I've been trying to write a simple web service in Prolog and was wondering how I can handle optional parameters. I thought that with `library(http/http_parameters)` it may be as simple as that:

```
my_request_handler(Request) :-
    http_parameters(Request, [ param_1(Param1, []), param_2(Param2, []) ]),
    ... ### handle both parameters

my_request_handler(Request) :-
    http_parameters(Request, [ param_1(Param1, []) ]),
    ... ### handle only param_1
```

so if `param_2` is not provided the engine will backtrack to the second rule. But in SWI-Prolog `http_parameters` raises exception if parameters do not match the specification and so the code breaks on the first rule rather than trying to evaluate the second one.

Unfortunately, adding `optional(true)` to the `param_2` specification makes it unbound and forces me to use a conditional check like this:

```
my_request_handler(Request) :-
    http_parameters(Request, [ param_1(Param1, []), param_2(Param2, [optional(true)]) ]),
    (error:text(Param2) ->
       ... ### handle both parameters
    ;
       ... ### handle only param_1
    ).
```

Is this the best way of doing things or I am missing something? I guess, that the conditionals become much uglier if more than one parameter is optional...

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Summary

There are at least two ways out:

1. You can combine `optional/1` with **`default/1`**, and specify a value that can otherwise not occur.
2. You can specify `list/1` to obtain a **list**, and use pattern matching to distinguish the cases.

See below for more details.

## Using `default/1`

For example, to implement option 1, you could write:

```
my_request_handler(Request) :-
        http_parameters(Request, [ param_1(Param1, []),
                                   param_2(Param2, [optional(true),
                                                    default(none)])
                                 ]),
        handle_parameters_(Param1, Param2).
```

and distinguish the cases with [**`if_3`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39833370/what-use-does-if-3-have):

```
handle_parameters_(Param1, Param2) :-
        if_(Param2 = none,
            Then,
            Else).
```

Main drawback: To really distinguish the cases by **pattern matching**, you would have to convert this to a **clean** representation. Without this, you also risk that one of the attributes legitimately overlaps with the value you are using to mean "not specified". One suitable representation could look like this:

- `none` for "not specified"
- `atom(A)` for the **atom** `A`.

However, this conversion again requires that you manually implement the distinction, using for example `var/1` in the example you posted.

## Using `list/1`

Option (2) is somewhat less error-prone, albeit slightly more indirect.

You can apply it like this:

```
my_request_handler(Request) :-
        http_parameters(Request, [ param_1(Param1, []),
                                   param_2(Param2, [list(atom)])
                                 ]),
        handle_parameters_(Param1, Param2).
```

Then, you can distinguish the cases by **pattern matching**:

```
handle_parameters_(Param1, []) :-
        ...
handle_parameters_(Param1, [Param2]) :-
        ...
```

This seems quite OK to me.