# What use does if_/3 have?

Tags: if-statement, prolog, logical-purity

The predicate **[`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358456/prolog-union-for-a-u-b-u-c/27358600#27358600)** seems to be [fairly popular](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprolog%5D+if_) among the few main contributors in the Prolog part of Stack Overflow.

This predicate is implemented as such, courtesy of @false:

```
if_(If_1, Then_0, Else_0) :-
   call(If_1, T),
   (  T == true -> call(Then_0)
   ;  T == false -> call(Else_0)
   ;  nonvar(T) -> throw(error(type_error(boolean,T),_))
   ;  /* var(T) */ throw(error(instantiation_error,_))
   ).
```

However, I have been unable to find a **clear, simple, and concise** explanation of what this predicate does, and what use it has compared to e.g. the classical if-then-else construct of Prolog `if -> then ; else`.

Most links I have found directly use this predicate and provide little explanation as to why it gets used, that a non-expert in Prolog could understand easily.

Comment: You need to be an expert in more than Prolog to understand this ;-) The cryptic name doesn't help, either. Keep in mind the first argument cannot be just anything: it needs to be a predicate that succeeds deterministically and unifies its second argument with either `true` or `false` ("reification"), otherwise an error is thrown.

Comment: PS: I am not saying it not a useful predicate, but there is more to it than meets the eye. Hiding ugliness beneath layers of indirection is a common feature of the Prolog programming style promoted by the "few main contributors" you are talking about. I hope I don't come across as too negative, I do think it is a good thing to have such constructs and to try to apply them to existing and new problems.

Comment: PPS: In particular, study the definition of `=/3`, right below `if_/3`, [from your own link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/1812457), where you see what it takes to write a predicate that plays along nicely with `if_/3`.

Comment: D'abord, did you read https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01590?

Comment: @false I had glanced through it, but I am asking a question from the point of view of a programmer, which should not have to read scientific papers to understand what a predicate does and when to use it.

Comment: @Fatalize to be fair, there is plenty of code in that paper, and the text just provides the necessary context.

Comment: @Boris: A suggestion (to your deleted answer) `is_a/2` -> `is_t/2`.

Comment: @Boris: A further suggestion: Use the suffixes `_0` for variables that describge goals, `_1` for variables that need an argument to have a goal &ct

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In old-fashioned Prolog code, the following pattern arises rather frequently:

```
predicate([], ...).
predicate([L|Ls], ...) :-
        condition(L),
        then(Ls, ...).
predicate([L|Ls], ...) :-
        \+ condition(L),
        else(Ls, ...).
```

I am using lists here as an example where this occurs (see for example `include/3`, `exclude/3` etc.), although the pattern of course also occurs elsewhere.

The tragic is the following:

- For an **instantiated** list, pattern matching can distinguish the first clause from the remaining two, but it cannot distinguish the second one from the last one because they *both* have `'.'(_, _)` as the primary functor and arity of their first argument.
- The conditions in which the last two clauses apply are obviously **mutually exclusive**.
- Thus, when everything is known, we want to obtain an efficient, **deterministic** predicate that *does not leave choice points*, and ideally does not even *create* choice points.
- *However*, as long as not everything can be safely determined, we want to benefit from **backtracking** to see **all solutions**, so we cannot afford to commit to either of the clauses.

In summary, the existing constructs and language features all fall short in some way to express a pattern that often occurs in practice. Therefore, for decades, it seemed necessary to *compromise*. And you can make a pretty good guess in which direction the "compromises" usually go in the Prolog community: Almost invariably, *correctness is sacrificed for efficiency* in case of doubt. After all, who cares about correct results as long as your programs are fast, right? Therefore, until the invention of `if_/3`, this was frequently *wrongly* written as:

```
predicate([], ...).
predicate([L|Ls], ...) :-
        (    condition(L) ->
             then(Ls, ...).
        ;    else(Ls, ...).
        )
```

The **mistake** in this is of course that when the elements are *not* sufficiently instantiated, then this may *incorrectly* commit to one branch even though *both* alternatives are logically possible. For this reason, using if-then-else is almost always declaratively wrong, and stands massively in the way of declarative debugging approaches due to its violation of the most elementary properties we expect from pure Prolog programs.

---

Using `if_/3`, you can write this as:

```
predicate([], ...).
predicate([L|Ls], ...) :-
        if_(condition(L),
            then(Ls, ...),
            else(Ls, ...)).
```

and **retain all desirable aspects**. This is:

- **deterministic** if everything can be *safely* decided
- **efficient** in that it does not even create choice points
- **complete** in that you never *incorrectly* commit to one particular branch.

The **price** of this is rather affordable: As Boris mentioned in the comments, you need to implement a **reification**. I have now some experience with this and found it rather easy with some practice.

**Good news everyone**: In many cases, `condition` is of the form `(=)/2`, or `(#=)/2`, and the first even ships with [**`library(reif)`**](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl) **for free**.

For more information, see [**Indexing dif/2**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01590) by Ulrich Neumerkel and Stefan Kral!

Comment: Is it correct to get from this answer that one should always use `if_` instead of `if -> then ; else` (excluding specific situations), similarly to how `CLP(FD)` should always be used instead of low-level arithmetic (excluding specific situations)?

Comment: I would phrase it like this: `if -> then ; else` leads to **wrong** programs in almost all cases. The only reason to use this extra-logical construct is to make programs more efficient, very often at the price of correctness. `if_/3`, on the other hand, *combines* correctness with acceptable efficiency, at a very affordable price: It takes a reification (often it is `(=)/3`, which is already included in the library) and a bit of learning the new construct. The best way, always, is to use pattern matching wherever possible. If that is not possible, `if_/3` is a *very* good alternative!

Comment: @Fatalize: Please read [Section 2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01590) which is called "The declarative limits of Prolog’s if-then-else" to answer your question about the traditional if-then-else.

Answer (score 12):

Let's try to solve a simple problem using `if_/3`; for example, I will try to partition a list (sorted on a predicate `p/2`) in two lists: a prefix in which, for every element `X`, we have `p(X, true)`, and a rest (in which, if the list was sorted on `p/2`, we would have `p(X, false)`.

I will use the library `reif` as [here](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/swi/reif.pl). So, here is the complete code of my program:

```
:- use_module(reif).

pred_prefix(Pred_1, List, L_true, L_false) :-
        pred_prefix_aux(List, Pred_1, L_true, L_false).

pred_prefix_aux([], _, [], []).
pred_prefix_aux([X|Xs], Pred_1, True, False) :-
        if_(    call(Pred_1, X),
                (       True = [X|True0],
                        pred_prefix_aux(Xs, Pred_1, True0, False)
                ),
                (       True = [],
                        False = [X|Xs]
                )
        ).
```

The predicate passed to this meta-predicate will take two arguments: the first is the current list element, and the second will be either `true` or `false`. Ideally, this predicate will always succeed and not leave behind choice points.

In the first argument of `if_/2`, the predicate is evaluated with the current list element; the second argument is what happens when `true`; the third argument is what happens when `false`.

With this, I can split a list in leading `a`s and a rest:

```
?- pred_prefix([X, B]>>(=(a, X, B)), [a,a,b], T, F).
T = [a, a],
F = [b].

?- pred_prefix([X, B]>>(=(a, X, B)), [b,c,d], T, F).
T = [],
F = [b, c, d].

?- pred_prefix([X, B]>>(=(a, X, B)), [b,a], T, F).
T = [],
F = [b, a].

?- pred_prefix([X, B]>>(=(a, X, B)), List, T, F).
List = T, T = F, F = [] ;
List = T, T = [a],
F = [] ;
List = T, T = [a, a],
F = [] ;
List = T, T = [a, a, a],
F = [] .
```

How can you get rid of leading 0's for example:

```
?- pred_prefix([X, B]>>(=(0, X, B)), [0,0,1,2,0,3], _, F).
F = [1, 2, 0, 3].
```

Of course, this could have been written much simpler:

```
drop_leading_zeros([], []).
drop_leading_zeros([X|Xs], Rest) :-
    if_(=(0, X), drop_leading_zeros(Xs, Rest), [X|Xs] = Rest).
```

Here I have just removed all unnecessary arguments.

If you would have to do this *without* `if_/3`, you would have had to write:

```
drop_leading_zeros_a([], []).
drop_leading_zeros_a([X|Xs], Rest) :-
    =(0, X, T),
    (   T == true -> drop_leading_zeros_a(Xs, Rest)
    ;   T == false -> [X|Xs] = Rest
    ).
```

Here, we assume that `=/3` will indeed always succeed without choice points and the `T` will always be either `true` or `false`.

And, if we didn't have `=/3` either, you'd write:

```
drop_leading_zeros_full([], []).
drop_leading_zeros_full([X|Xs], Rest) :-
    (   X == 0 -> T = true
    ;   X \= 0 -> T = false
    ;   T = true, X = 0
    ;   T = false, dif(0, X)
    ),
    (   T == true -> drop_leading_zeros_full(Xs, Rest)
    ;   T == false -> [X|Xs] = Rest
    ).
```

which is not ideal. But now at least you can see for yourself, in one single place, what is actually going on.

PS: Please read the code and the top level interaction carefully.

Comment: For SWI, there is [this version](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/swi/reif.pl). However, please note that in SWI, the semantics of meta-predicates is highly instable (in contrast to SICStus).