# How do I change position of two elements in a list(PROLOG)

Tags: prolog

predicate `change_pos(E1, E2,Lin,Lout).`

The `Lin` has any number of elements, and I need to change all occurences of `E1` to `E2`, and vice-versa. And return in `Lout`.

I was thinking to do something like this:

```
change(X, Y, [], []).
change(X, Y, [X|L], [Y,L1]):- change(X,Y,L,L1).
change(X, Y, [Z|L], [Z,L1]:- X \== Z, change(X,Y,L,L1).
```

But this way is not swiping two number of the list

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: And you're not changing the position of two elements. You're replacing elements. Two different things.

Comment: You should try something and then show us, rather than just asking us to do the work for you.

Comment: I was thinking to do something like this:

change(X, Y, [], []).

change(X, Y, [X|L], [Y,L1]):- change(X,Y,L,L1).

change(X, Y, [Z|L], [Z,L1]:- X \== Z, change(X,Y,L,L1).

But this way is not swiping two number of the list

Comment: @DanielLyons could you answer me?

Comment: @JessicaSimoes- I think Daniel was letting you know how to ask your question. I don't think he was suggesting he would answer it for you.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I understand, I mean if he could give me a light, could you?

Comment: @JessicaSimoes - Try changing `[Y,L1]` to `[Y|L1]` & `[Z,L1]` to `[Z|L1]`.

Comment: You're really close! You're also missing a `)` before the `:-` on the third clause.

Comment: @false - I voted to close on the OP's original post. Take a look at that revision.

Comment: @Enigmativity Oh I see. You copied the OP's comment code into the question. I usually try to get them to do it. :) But then, given that code, I don't think there was a basis for closure.

Comment: @false - I've voted to re-open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Your base case (the empty lists) and your second rule (swap `X` for `Y`) are basically fine (apart from the details pointed out in the comments). However, you are missing a rule for *vice-versa* (swap `Y` for `X`). And in your last rule you likely want to make sure that `Z` differs not only from `X` but also from `Y`, otherwise `Z` would be subject to rule two or three.

```
change(X, Y, [], []).
change(X, Y, [X|L], [Y|L1]) :-
   change(X,Y,L,L1).
change(X, Y, [Y|L], [X|L1]) :-   % <- vice versa case
   change(X,Y,L,L1).
change(X, Y, [Z|L], [Z|L1]) :-
      dif(X,Z),                  % <- neither X=Z
      dif(Y,Z),                  % <- nor vice versa
      change(X,Y,L,L1).
```

Here are some example queries. *What does* `[1,2,3,4]` *look like after swapping* `1` *with* `2` *and vice versa?*

```
   ?- change(1,2,[1,2,3,4],L).
L = [2,1,3,4] ? ;
no
```

*What did* `[2,1,3,4]` *look like before swapping* `1` *with* `2` *and vice versa?*

```
   ?- change(1,2,L,[2,1,3,4]).
L = [1,2,3,4] ? ;
no
```

*Which elements have been swapped in* `[1,2,3,4]` *if the resulting list is* `[2,1,3,4]` *?*

```
   ?- change(X,Y,[1,2,3,4],[2,1,3,4]).
X = 1,
Y = 2 ? ;
X = 2,
Y = 1 ? ;
no
```

Comment: All this `; no` ... And what about `change(a,a,[a],[a])`'s two (2) redundant answers?

Comment: @false: Fun fact: In Yap the query `?- change(a,a,[a],[a]).` succeeds deterministically. :-)

Comment: In the same way as `repeat.`? Yes?

Comment: @false: Yes. Interesting, I didn't notice that yet. If I'm reading 8.15.3.1 correctly `repeat/0` should not terminate but produce `true` as long as the user hits `;`, right?

Comment: Indeed. That's a 1970s feature of old toplevels: if there is no variable substitution, simply stop.

Comment: @false: That link ... :-D

Answer (score 4):

I'm supposing, since this is homework, it's an exercise to learn list processing and recursion. But in Prolog, a common tool for processing each term in turn in a list is `maplist`:

```
% Rule for changing one element
change_element(X, Y, X, Y).
change_element(X, Y, Y, X).
change_element(X, Y, Z, Z) :- dif(X, Z), dif(Y, Z).

% Rule for changing a list
change(X, Y, L1, L2) :-
    maplist(change_element(X, Y), L1, L2).
```

Which yields:

```
?- change(a, b, [a,b,c,b,a], L).

L = [b, a, c, a, b] ? ;

no
?-
```

---

For a *determinate* solution, you can use [if_/3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39833370/what-use-does-if-3-have):

```
change1(X, Y, A, B) :-
    if_(=(Y, A), B = X, A = B).
change2(X, Y, A, B) :-
    if_(=(X, A), B = Y, change1(X, Y, A, B)).

change(X, Y, L1, L2) :- maplist(change2(X, Y), L1, L2).
```

Which yields:

```
?- change(a, b, [a,b,c,b,a], L).

L = [b, a, c, a, b].

?-
```

Comment: Can you make this determinate?

Comment: ... ideally in a separate answer which has been prevented by this closing

Comment: Now you can make another answer! (BTW, = can be used as an operator and `change1/4` is not needed as a separate predicate