# Find elements before X on list

Tags: prolog, logic

I'm learning Prolog and this may be a very simple question.

Say I just need a procedure that does the following:

```
before(5, [1, 2, 4, 5, 36, 5], Result)
...
Result = [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

I'm aware that if N is the first element, I can add the following rule:

```
before(N, [N|_], Result) :- Result = [N].
```

But what should I do for the other cases?

Comment: In the other case, the second argument is a list `[X|Tail]` where `X` is also at the head of the overall result list. All that remains is to find (by recursion) the result list for the `Tail` list.

Comment: Thanks @IsabelleNewbie. Then I have `before(N, [X|Tail], Result)`. My idea was to add X to Result list until X was N, but for what I read I can't change a variable after defining it. Could you help with this?

Comment: If you have `[X|Tail]` and `N` is not `X`, then the result must be of the form `[X|ResultTail]`.

Comment: Thanks @IsabelleNewbie. Working now!

Comment: Simple solution would be: `before(N, L, Result) :- once(append(Result, [N|_], List)).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution:

```
before( _, [], []).
before( N, [N|_], [N]).
before( N, [X|T], [X|Res]):- dif(N,X), before( N, T, Res).
```

Example:

```
?- before(5, [1, 2, 4, 5, 36, 5], Result).
Result = [1, 2, 4, 5] ;
false.
```

And a more elegant solution using [**`if_/3`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39833370/what-use-does-if-3-have) from [***`library(reif)`***](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl):

```
:- use_module(library(reif)).

before( _, []   , [] ).
before( N, [X|T], Res):- 
            if_( X = N, 
                 Res = [N],
                 (before( N, T, Res2), Res = [X|Res2] )
               ).
```

Example:

```
?- before(5, [1, 2, 4, 5, 36, 5], Result).
Result = [1, 2, 4, 5].
```

As you can see this is deterministic it only gave one answer and no choice point left. In the first answer same result was given but there was a choice point returning false. This second answer which gives right result avoiding this useless choice point is more efficient. Also in