# Prolog if-then-else constructs: -> vs *-> vs. if_/3

Tags: if-statement, prolog, control-structure, logical-purity, implication

As noted in another StackOverflow answer that I can't seem to find anymore, this pattern emerges frequently in practical Prolog code:

```
pred(X) :-
    guard(X),
    ...
pred(X) :-
    \+ guard(X),
    ...
```

and many people try to condense this to

```
pred(X) :-
    (guard(X) ->
    ...
    ;
    ...).
```

However as we all know, the arrow structure destroys choice points and isn't logical.

In Ulrich Neumerkel's and Stefan Kral's [*Indexing dif/2*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01590), a predicate called `if_/3` is proposed that is monotonic and logical, however in the paper they mention another construct which caught my eye: `*->`.

The `*->` construct functions exactly like the unsugared guard clause example above, and thus it seems perfect for my uses as I don't want to have a reified condition which is required by `if_/3` and I don't care about extra choice points that much. If I'm not mistaken (edit: I am), it offers the same semantics as `if_/3` but without the requirement of adding the "reification" to the condition predicate.

However in the SWI documentation for it, it claims that ["this construct is rarely used,"](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=control#*->/2) which seems weird to me. `*->` seems to me like it's strictly better than `->` when you're trying to do pure logical programming. Is there any reason to avoid this structure, or is there an even better alternative to the entire guard clause / negated guard clause pattern?

Comment: *If I'm not mistaken, it offers the same semantics as `if_/3`*. You are mistaken. Please refer to *2 The declarative limits of Prolog’s if-then-else*, last paragraph: *Even
the “soft cut”-versions
`if/3`
and
`(*->)/2`
of SICStus and SWI respectively, exhibit the same
problems as Prolog’s unsound negation.*

Comment: Here is a definition of `if/3` (not efficient as it executes the guard twice): `if(G_0, Then_0, _) :- G_0, Then_0. if(G_0, _, Else_0) :- \+ G_0, Else_0.` You see the `\+`? It's full of impurity!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try it out! The pattern you give is:

```
pred(X) :-
    (    guard(X) ->
         ...
    ;    ...
    ).
```

I now use `(*->)/2` and fill out the "..." as follows:

```
pred(X) :-
        (   guard(X) *->
            false
        ;   true
        ).
```

Further, as `guard/1`, I define the obviously *pure* predicate:

```
guard(a).
```

Now, let's ask `pred/1` the **most general query**: *Are there any solutions at all?*

```
?- pred(X).
false.
```

So, according to the predicate, **there is no term `X` such that `pred(X)` is true**.

But that's *wrong*, because there is in fact such a term:

```
?- pred(b).
true.
```

In fact, `pred/1` has *infinitely many solutions*. In such a situation, is it acceptable that the predicate states there are none at all? Sure thing, because the answer was computed *extremely efficiently*, is it not so?

We conclude that `(*->)/2` shares an important drawback of `(->)/2`: It may *incorrectly* commit to one of the branches in cases where a *different* branch would be applicable if only the variables that occur in the condition were further instantiated. A predicate that depends on the *instantiation* of its arguments in such a way can never be pure, because it counteracts the monotonic reasoning we expect to be applicable to pure logic programs. In particular, from a logical perspective, since `pred(b)` holds, we expect that `pred(X)`, which is a **generalization** of `pred(b)`, *must not fail*. Once this property breaks, you can no longer apply declarative debugging and other important approaches that let you more easily understand, reason about and manage Prolog programs, and which constitute a major attraction of declarative programming in the first place.

The question you mentioned is probably [**What uses does `if_3/` have**?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39833370/what-use-does-if-3-have).

Comment: Okay, I get it now. It seems to me that if we made `\+/1` work in the same way as `dif/2` (that is, it imposed a constraint that a certain expression will never be proven), we could get proper behavior out of `*->` by making it such that if the test clause fails (for example `guard(X)`), it introduces a constraint `\+guard(X)` and we could avoid the whole runaround of reification for `if_/3` clauses, no?

Comment: Please note that to make `(\+)/1` work in the same way as `dif/2` is tantamount to *constructive negation*. You find a discussion on this in *7 General reification*. At least from the example given, general reification is much more costly compared to the "whole runaround" of `if_/3`.

Comment: @false Awesome, thanks for the tip. It seems like we can accomplish pure behavior by changing the original example to have `freeze(X, \+guard(X))`, and this looks like it's working the same as the `if_/3` form. I'm not sure of the performance implications of this though.

Comment: @NameMcChange: Depending on the very precise meaning of `guard/1`, you may need `when(ground(X), \+ guard(X))` or something in between. That's exactly what makes constructive negation so expensive. You need more or less a meta-interpreter that watches `guard/1`'s behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The usually named *soft-cut* control construct is available in several Prolog systems. CxProlog, ECLiPSe, JIProlog, SWI-Prolog, and YAP provide it as both a `*->/2` predicate and infix operator. Ciao Prolog, SICStus Prolog, and YAP provide an `if/3` predicate with the same semantics.

My main use of this *soft-cut* control construct is in the implementation of *coinduction* in Logtalk, where it plays a critical role. Outside of this case, I rarely use it.

The `->/2`, on the other hand, it's widely used. The implicit cut in the *if*  part is local to the construct and its usage avoids, as in your example, trying to prove the guard twice, which can be computationally expensive. It may not be *pure* but, as with the cut, as long as you're fully aware of its pros and cons, it's a useful control construct.

P.S. Logtalk provides unit tests for this control construct for the `*->/2` variant at https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/tests/prolog/control/soft_cut_2_3 and for the `if/3` variant at https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/tests/prolog/control/if_3